# height issue in firefox in the th tag

Tags: html, css

I've come across an issue. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/a2bPk/1/

I want the height of each of the columns to be equal. The text in the column headers can be free flowing, wrapping. They can wrap into multiple lines.

Here is the part of code which gives me achieve this in chrome and safari in mac and windows.

```
margin:auto;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
```

I have made a correction in the question. I want the content of each th tag to be of same height.

Comment: each table cell height is equal

Comment: if you want your text to stick to the top of the th, use `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: The content can't be same height, because it isn't the same content. If content have three lines, it have "three lines" height, but if have a single line it have "one line" height. Anyway, cells already have same height (as slash197 says). To achieve the background to cover all the cell, Sowmya's answer can do it.

Comment: I don't why my question is down voted. I think it is a good question I come across. If people don't have answers they can pass by. I expect a solution. Appreciate any help.

Comment: @RupamDatta Please, would you read our comments and give us your opinion to them, to help us continue study your question if applicable? Thanks!

Comment: @slash197 Thanks. I know the height of each cell is same in a table layout but my problem is different. My mad I had post it wrongly in the beginning.

Comment: @Brewal Thanks but my problem is different. Any other solution please.

Comment: @Arkana Hi Arkana. Thanks for the suggestion but that does not help. As you see my fiddle, I clearly mention that. I do need the yellow part to take the 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are writing `bg color` for `div` not for `th` that is why it is taking auto height.

Why don't you use like this

```
thead tr{
    background: #ff0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a2bPk/2/)**